# Ignore all fields (keys) into Mongo find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

[From documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) `find()` is defined like bellow:

> `db.collection.find(query, projection)`

where the `projection` is an object that *specifies the fields to return using projection operators*.

> To return all fields in the matching document, **omit this parameter.**

My question is that if there is any way to **ignore all fields** using `projection` object.

I want to receive a response like this:

> `[{}, {}, {}, {}]`

(an array with empty objects)

To ignore a key I use: `{"key": 0}`.
I've already tried `{"$all": 0}`  that seems that doesn't work.

How can I ignore all fields?

---

I know that I can use `count()` function, but this doesn't help me in this case.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Zirak I want to count how many documents are in the collection, but using `find()` and I don't want to get the content of documents, just how many they are.

Comment: Why don't you use `count()`? I am unsure how it doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore all fields, out of `_id`, you could use:

> db.collection.find(query, {$all: 1})

That will return:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("4d6bf563c2dbe2c5f220dc70") }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("4d6bf563c2dbe2c5f220dc71") }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("4d6bf563c2dbe2c5f220dc72") }

And to remove `_id` use:

> db.collection.find(query, {$all: 1, '_id': 0})

To return:

> {  }
> {  }
> {  }